# Do only gas planets have discs or even rocky planets may have them orbiting around?

Tags: astrophysics, orbital-motion, planets

Do only gas planets have discs or even rocky planets may have them orbiting around? If rocky planets are great in volume is then a higher chance for an orbiting disc to exist in the planetary orbit?

Comment: Are you asking about [ring systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_system)?

Comment: Even a rocky planet is bigger than you need. At least one dwarf planet [has multiple rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/50000_Quaoar#Rings). The moon Iapetus [may have had one](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1029/2005GL025386).

Answer (score 0):

There is no known reason why a rocky (or [terrestrial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrestrial_planet)) planet cannot have a ring system, although their smaller size and lower gravity makes this less likely for a terrestrial planet than for a gas giant. According to the [Wikipedia article on ring systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_system):

> It is also predicted that Phobos, a moon of Mars, will break up and form into a planetary ring in about 50 million years. Its low orbit, with an orbital period that is shorter than a Martian day, is decaying due to tidal deceleration.